# Why does the preposition used with **geht es ... um** vary?

Tags: preposition

A text I am studying has two uses of **geht es ... um** as follows.

> Bei einer Kur geht es um die Gesundheit.

and

> Mittlerweile geht es im All um die wissenschaftliche Forschung.

Why is **bei** the preposition in the first and **in** the preposition in the second?

Comment: bei einer Kur / im All

Answer (score 5):

The difference is the subject, not the usage of "geht es um". "All" has a spatial component, as it translates to "universe" or "outer space". "Kur" is not a location, thus a causal preposition is used.

Comment: Exactly the information I needed. Thank you.