# Why does the preposition differ in these cases?

Tags: preposition

This question is similar to [this one](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55274/44591) but that answer does not seem applicable.

Here are 2 uses of es geht um. Why are different prepositions (in/bei) used?

> Worum geht es **in** diesem Film?

> Worum geht es **bei** eurem Streit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions are about a relation, between a film and the plot in the first case, between a quarrel and the root cause in the other. The different prepositions illustrate a difference in the relationship:
In the first case, the plot is completely contained **in**side the film.
In the second case, quarrel and cause exist side **by** side, but separate.
OK, it is not necessary that the prepositions in both language are so similar, but here it helps to illustrate the preferred use.

Answer (score -1):

That's just personal preference of the speaker.
You can as well say:

> Worum geht es bei diesem Film?

and

> Worum geht es in eurem Streit?

Comment: "Worum geht es in eurem Streit" finde ich einigermaßen strange.

Comment: "Worum geht es in diesem Film?" und "Worum geht es bei diesem Film?" sind auch nicht so wirklich dasselbe.